# Add customer attribute with yes/no option

Tags: magento-2.1, module, database, customer-attribute

I need to create custom Customer Attribute with Yes/No option. I successfully created ones with Text input previously. What I need now is, create a separate attribute for set if Customer is on Hold or not. I've used mage2gen.com's module generator and I can see the attribute in backend. (When I tried to create new customer or edit customer). But thing is I'm not sure that data has been saved into the database. Basically what I need is,

1. Create customer module with yes/no or dropdown with two options. It should only be visible from admin area.no need to display anything in frontend.
2. check whether data is saved when customer is saved/updated.
3. Retrieve created customer attribute data using ObjectManager

Please help me out with this

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use This Module Please check! It's Free
https://store.magenest.com/magento-2/customer-attributes.html
Thanks!

Comment: It's Helpful For You?

Comment: Hi, while it's good extension, it doesn't fullfill my requirement. I need only to add yes/no field into admin area,not frontend.

Comment: You can set attribute Show on Storefront -> yes/no

Comment: I tried their demo. not working for my requirements. thank you for your help. if you know how to create a custom module, could you please help me with this? if you can